# Using UIViewController with a UIView - (Want to use UIScrollView instead) - How to make the switch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I need to implement a scrolling window in order to accommodate all the items on the form I am creating.  My current implementation is a UIViewController (that's vcAddCourse) and it has a UIView in it with my current form.

Here is what I have done to add the UIScrollView into the equation.

1) Using IB, I dragged a uiscrollview object 'into' the existing uiview object.
2) Using IB, Ctrl-dragged from file owner to the IBOutlet I created for the new uiscrollview
Here is how I init this controller.
3) I made sure that all the items on my form were now dragged to be under the UIScrollview object.

Finally, over in my .m file, in the ViewdidLoad() function, I added the following line:

```
theScroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(328, 680);
```

No joy.  I see the form but it does not scroll.

Note: this on iphone simulator.

What else must I do to swap out the UIView for the new UIScrollView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep things like these clear, I keep the scrollView and the (larger) subview separate in the xib file (as siblings). Your form should be on a UIView, and would be larger than the scrollview. That way you can use IB to layout the form exactly as you want. 
To make things work you just have to have the IBOutlets to the UIScrollView and the UIView, and add the view to the scrollview in the viewDidLoad method of your viewController:

[theScroller addSubView:formView];

I'm not exactly sure, but I don't think you have to set the contentSize manually after this, as it should automatically be made big enough to fit your view. If it's not working you might try this: 
theScroller.contentSize = formView.frame.size;

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, let me give that a shot.